# Not listing connected WiFi printer in android print panel

Tags: java, android, printing, epson, network-printers

I'm using following code to print web-view from android app.

```
    private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
          .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = 
             webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + 
                        " Print Test";

    printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
           new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
}
```

But android print panel not showing the available WiFi printer in print panel.

**Note:**

- It shows "Google cloud print" and "save as PDF" option in android print panel.(API LEVEL 19)
- I am using the **Epson printer** and I have installed **Epson Printer Enabler** on my android device.

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. It appears that some devices lack cloud printing and therefore will need to install the official Google Cloud Print plugin/app.

You could suggest users to download the app if there are no printers being displayed.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudprint